# Count a 'quantity' column in Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, count

I have a table that registers if work is in progress for certain tasks, an entry is logged if work has begun and if work has been completed. The problem I have is that the expense is only logged with the 'started' entries but I need to only count the expense if the task is completed ie has a completed entry. Each task can only be undertaken once, ie you will not see 2 task1 starts without a 'finished' logged in between.

Eg

I want to count the expense for completed task1's

```
Task (NvarChar)Time(datetime2) Status(nvarchar) Expense(Int)
task1 101/01/01 12:00 started 20
task2 01/01/01 11:30 finished null
task2 01/01/01 11:00 started 10
task1 01/01/01 10:30 finished null
task2 01/01/01 10:20 finished null
task1 01/01/01 10:15 started null
task2 01/01/01 10:00 started 30
```

Answer (score 0):

If your table has a task_id it is possible with something like that :

```
select task, expense from
tasks where status = 'started' and exists 
(select null from tasks t where task_id = task_id and status = 'finished')
```

If you want more data, like the time spent on the task, this query wouldnt do it

Comment: Problem is that same task_id take be "restarted", so you need to develop logic to get one that corresponds, example: last one before...

Comment: @igr tasks can not be restarted without being restarted first.

Comment: so you can create a temporary table with a flag status, and you update this flag with +1 when started and -1 when finished, +1 when restarted. and then you delete those where the status <> 0. you finally can do a join with the tasks table.

Comment: @Jonysuise Would your suggested query not simply select task and expenses that are started and not finished? I want to count the expense column for completed task1's

Comment: you mean it can't be restarted before finished in last "incarnation" ?

Comment: my above query selects those tasks with a started and a finished row.

Comment: @igr Good idea, this seems long winded but i like it

Comment: @Jonysuise I'll try it out and insert a count if it works into my issue, cheers

Comment: Ok so i did this and it seems to work:
select task, expense from
tasks t1 where task = 'task1' and status = 'started' and exists(Select * from tasks t2 where t2.Time > t1.Time). Ie if there exists a entry for task1 after anything selected in first line

Comment: We can chat if you want. I dont get what is wrong now. How do i get to chat with you ?

Answer (score 0):

If the same id can be reused, and you're on SQL 2012, you may want to see if the lag() windowing function can help here.